# Any downside to overriding ConfigParser get() method to include an eval?

Tags: python, configparser

I'm creating a subclass of ConfigParser that is easier for me to use throughout my project:

```
class MyConfiguration(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        ConfigParser.ConfigParser.__init__(self)
        self.readfp(open(filename))

    def get(self, section, option):
        return eval(ConfigParser.ConfigParser.get(self, section, option))
```

Question: are there any downsides (security, unintended consequences) to overriding the get() method with one that includes eval?

I'd rather bake the eval into the MyConfiguration class because I want to use Python data types (tuples, etc.) in my config files but I don't want to deal with evals all over my project code.

Comment: You mean, apart from all the usual downsides of eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only interest in `eval` is literal values as you seem to indicate, then you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast-helpers)

This will read tuple literals, list literals and others and is safe to use because it is selective about what it will accept.

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = ast.literal_eval('(1, 2, 3)')
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
>>> b = ast.literal_eval('__import__("evil")')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 68, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 67, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Use cases like this are exactly what this function is intended for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is a good idea to eval an arbitary text that may be contained in the config file. A normal call to eval is usually considered unsafe.

See:

1. [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings)
2. [Use of eval in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087255/use-of-eval-in-python)

If you want to use python data types, then it is much better to store it as a python module and import it. This might be a better solution in this case.

You can split up the config file as those containing python data types in a python module and keeping the rest as config file that can be parsed by configparser.

Comment: So is the typical use of ConfigParser to create and use configuration files with basic data types (i.e. those for which there is a specific get() method, such as str, int, float, boolean)? Or are containers allowed, but the eval is usually done in the calling class (which probably has a better way of handling the eval)?

Comment: @MikeRand: Yes, it is better to call eval in the calling class. While my answer points to issues with eval, aaronasterling provides a better answer. You can use that.