# Set string as variable name

Tags: python, string, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use a string with the same name of an object in Python to access the object itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396706/how-can-i-use-a-string-with-the-same-name-of-an-object-in-python-to-access-the-o)

I'm trying to change name to a variable depending on the result of a match...

```
inds_EUR = [whatever]
inds_AFR = [foo]
inds_ASN = [other]

pop=inds_EUR ##imagine this is the case
for pp in ('EUR', 'AFR', 'ASN'):
    if pp in pop:
    paap='inds_'+str(pp)        
    break
foos=eval(paap)
```

What I'm tryin, is to set "foos" as the list to pass to this expression

```
matches = [item for item in inds_vcf if item in foos]
```

It works, but don't know if it dangerous to use this eval() expression, here as it could be if using vars()
Am I doing it the right way?

Thanks in advance,

peixe

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary?

Comment: I'd really suggest you to take a look at the duplicate question because there are (imho) very good comments and answers.

Comment: ok, That's what i´ll do.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
inds = {'EUR': [whatever],
        'AFR': [foo],
        'ASN': [other]}

foos = inds['EUR']
```

Comment: Even if now I know this is the way to go, i'll take a look to the duplicate.
Thanks, @eumiro

Comment: It's good to have at least one answer, even on closed question.