# Dynamic Self Referencing Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, multiprocessing

I have seen [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738381/what-do-i-do-when-i-need-a-self-referential-dictionary) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205469/referencing-and-setting-variables-in-python-dicts) [questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary) on making dictionaries which reference other parts of the same dictionary, but they all seem to be for static returns whenever the dictionary is first created.
Is there a way to do this and stay dynamic?

Like so:

```
# Lets just say we have a barn with lots of animals
# and the pigs always eat 2 chickens, so there has to always be 2 chickens per pig
def make_barn():
    barn = {'pig': 0, 'cow': 0, 'chicken': 2*barn['pig']}
    return barn
```

Such that this:

```
barn['pig'] = 3
print barn
```

will print this:

```
{'pig':3, 'chicken':6, 'cow':0}
```

I tried using lambda functions or classes, but I am trying to pickle this as a HUGE dictionary for the purpose of passing in between processes in the `multiprocessing` module and that module didn't seem to like `lambda` or `class` structures.

**Edit:**

I tried using the answer given in a multiprocessing script and it appears that it isn't picklable:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
from UserDict import UserDict

class Barn(UserDict):
    '''Barn automatically sets correct values for chickens.
    TBD: What to do if chickens get changed?'''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        UserDict.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        pigs = self.data.get('pigs', None)
        if pigs is not None:
            self.data['chicken'] = pigs * 2

    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'pigs':
            self.data['chicken'] = value * 2
        self.data[name] = value

def count_animals(barn_record):
    for animal in random.randrange(0,10,1):
        barn_record['pigs'] = animal

# We need this to 'if __name__ == '__main__':' business to avoid having too many farms created continuously
# See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923706/multiprocessing-launching-too-many-instances-of-python-vm
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    barn_record = manager.dict({'pigs':3,'cows':2})
    farm = mp.Process(target = count_animals, args=(manager,))
    farm.start()
    print barn_record
```

Comment: Why is this a dictionary and not a class?

Comment: I need it to be a data type that can be passed between processes easily in a pipe or through a manager.  I actually made my whole program in an OO way, and then found out after it was done how incredibly slow and limited it was in use, so I am trying to make it multiprocessed now.
My thought was to make a big dictionary (of dictionaries of dictionaries..etc.) that held the objects as keys and their properties as values, which I could alter and then use in the functions in the processes.
If this is a bad idea, I am open to hear better designs, but that made the most sense to me so far.

Comment: it's really not clear what you want here.  it's trivial to write `barn = {'pig': 0, 'cow': 0}; barn['chicken'] = 2*barn['pig']` but presumably that's not what you want (and doesn't involve references anyway - the last entry is just zero)...

Comment: I would like for it to be _dynamic_. Such that whenever you execute `barn['pig'] = 4`, then `print barn` will return `{'pig':4, 'cow':0, 'chicken':8}`  

I edited the question to help display this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps? Tested with Python 2.7.

```
from UserDict import UserDict

class Barn(UserDict):
    '''Barn automatically sets correct values for chickens.
    TBD: What to do if chickens get changed?'''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        UserDict.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        pigs = self.data.get('pigs', None)
        if pigs is not None:
            self.data['chicken'] = pigs * 2

    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'pigs':
            self.data['chicken'] = value * 2
        self.data[name] = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Barn(cows=1, pigs=2)
    print b
    b['pigs'] = 3
    print b
```

Running that should produce something like this:

```
{'cows': 1, 'chicken': 4, 'pigs': 2}
{'cows': 1, 'chicken': 6, 'pigs': 3}
```

Comment: Wow! I had not seen this in the documentation, that's fantastic.  Hopefully it will pickle well, which would make sense since it is a dictionary.