# Update the referred variable in dictionary is not working

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

I have a dictionary where the value is a variable. When I update the dictionary based on some condition, the 'dictionary element' is updated, but not the referred variable

My code is something like

```
my_bool = True
my_count_dictionary={'name': my_bool}
my_count_dictionary['name'] = not my_count_dictionary['name'] #Need to toggle it
print (my_count_dictionary['name'])
print (my_count)
```

I am expecting the output like

```
False
False
```

but i am getting

```
False
True
```

The original variable is still not updated.  I am from C background. I guess i am expecting something like a reference here. Is it possible in python?

Comment: `+=` does not work in-place here, despite the syntax. Integers are immutable so a new value is returned and the object that `my_count` references is left untouched

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an integer by reference in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205469/referencing-and-setting-variables-in-python-dicts)

Comment: Infact i need it for a boolean type