# Use a variable to call a global list in python?

Tags: python, variables, global

I want to use a variable to call a global list with the same name. So, for example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [2,3,4,5]

def function(i):
    return i

function(x)
    expected output -> [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: pass x or y to the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a string with the same name of an object in Python to access the object itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396706/how-can-i-use-a-string-with-the-same-name-of-an-object-in-python-to-access-the-o)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean that

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> x == function('x')
True
```

where passing the string `'x'` to the function returns the list assigned to `x`.

You don't want to write code that depends on the *names* of variables;  instead, keep a dictionary that maps strings to your lists.

```
>>> d = dict(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> d['x']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: The `assert` thing is confusing to a beginner like OP seems to be. Otherwise, fully agree (+1).

Comment: Good point; I don't need it for the example.