# Convert string variables into other types

Tags: python, types, casting, python-2.7

I have a class which hold some variables as strings. e.g.

```
x = "1"
y = "2.0"
z = "timedelta(seconds=10)"
```

As you can see above the variables are actually int/float/timedelta-types.
I need to return these variables with their real type. (x should be returned as a int, y should be returned as a float, z should be returned as datetime.timedelta)

I was thinking of changing the **getattr** and try to find out the type before returning the value, but the small test I did, does not seem to work:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def test():
    string = "timedelta(seconds=10)"
    x = eval(string)
    print x
    print type(x)
    if type(x) == 'datetime.timedelta':
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```

The output is:

```
0:00:10
<type 'datetime.timedelta'>
NO
```

why is the if-case returning false? is there a better way to return these variables with the real type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `type(x)` returns `type` not string. Instead use:

```
type(x) == datetime.timedelta

# or, the better Python practice

isinstance(x, datetime.timedelta)
```

Comment: does not seem to work.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eval.py", line 14, in <module>
    test()
  File "eval.py", line 8, in test
    if isinstance(x, datetime.timedelta):
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Comment: It's because you have `from datetime import datetime` and in my example I refer to `timedelta` via a full "module path". Just replace `datetime.timedelta` with `timedelta`. And note that using `eval()` is considered a VERY bad practice in Python, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087255/use-of-eval-in-python for details.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a type and a string. Try this instead:

```
>>> type(x) == timedelta
True
```

Answer (score 1):

you are comparing string with type , hence it is returning false.

It's best if you use :

```
 isinstance(x, datetime.timedelta)
```

See this piece of code, it clearly tells you how to check for type :

```
    >>> foo = {}

    >>> type(foo)
    <type 'dict'>

    >>> class MyDict(dict):
    ...     pass

    >>> bar = MyDict()

    >>> type(bar)
    <class '__main__.MyDict'>

    >>> type(bar) == dict
    False                     # Unexpected result

    >>> isinstance(bar, dict)
    True                      # Expected result
```

Answer (score 0):

the type of `'datetime.timedelta'` is str. I think you mean to do `if type(x) == timedelta:`, which will do the correct typecheck.

Answer (score 0):

brief answer(I think this is what you want just for this question):

1.you import the **timedelta**,and it's name **timedelta._*name*_** is a string **'timedelta'**.

2.**x = eval(string)**,here x's **type** is **timedelta** which you imported aboved.

so, it's simple,just compare **type(x)._*name*_** with **timedelta._*name*_** if you just want compare them with string :)