# Run Python script saved as variable

Tags: python, eval

Is it possible to run a Python script which has been saved as a variable?

```
x = 'print ("Hello, World!")'
??? run(x) ???
```

I would like to be able to run the script without having to run:

```
python -c 'print ("Hello, World!")'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) statement is what you're looking for.

```
>>> cmd = 'print "Hello, world!"'
>>> exec cmd
Hello, world!
>>>
>>> cmd = """
... x = 4
... y = 3
... z = x*y + 1
... print 'z = {0}'.format(z)
... """
>>>
>>> exec cmd
z = 13
```

Please take appropriate cautions if you are including any user input in the string you are going to `exec`. Someone could easily input malicious statements that would be executed.

See also:

- [Use of eval in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087255/use-of-eval-in-python)
- [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want to do, it might help more to have another file and use Subprocess.Popen to open it as well. An example being asynchronous processes, a backend database, or another instance of an application to allow for a clean API between multiple processes :).

From the subprocess docs:

> ```
> ">>> import shlex, subprocess
> >>> command_line = raw_input()
> /bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
> >>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
> >>> print args
> ['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
> >>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!"
> ```
>
> [Subprocess Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Additionally you can use [`eval(expression[, globals[, locals]])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) which provides a more intuitive way for giving a symbol table (ok a namespace dictionary technically) to the string to be run :).