# Convert a string tuple to a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a user entered string which is already in tuple format and would like to convert/cast it to a actual tuple in python. How can I do this? E.g:

```
strTup = '(5, 6)'
```

Would like to convert the above to the tuple (5, 6). I tried `tuple(strTup)` which did not work as it made each character into its own tuple.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(strTup)`

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley, I hadn't even heard of the ast module; pretty neat!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087255/use-of-eval-in-python/1087625#1087625

Answer (score 24):

You can pass it to eval()  (note: this is *unsafe*):

Just do:

```py
strTup = '(5,6)'
eval(strTup)
```

Comment: This is very bad advice!!! A user entered string can arbitrary complex (and potentially malicious) code, and you will just blindly evaluate it on your server! Instead, use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Do note that if you are sure about the data, and the user has no realistic way of generating that data, you can still use `eval`, using `ast.literal_eval` is the way to go.