# Returning intermediate variable in Python using marco-like syntax in Julia

Tags: python

### Problem

In Julia, one could easily see the value of intermediate variable using `@show` marco for debugging purposes. For example

```
for i in 1:5
   @show i ^ 2
end
```

which will output

```
i ^ 2 = 1
i ^ 2 = 4
i ^ 2 = 9
i ^ 2 = 16
i ^ 2 = 25
```

However, in order to show intermediate value in Python, one have to write `print("<variable> = " + ...)`, which is too much work for debugging a large project. I am wondering if there is any way that could enable Python to have similar functionality as in Julia.

I previously saw people use decorator to acquire the program runtime (see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/169876)), which is quite similar to Julia marco. But I do not know how to get it to work here to show intermediate variable.

Could someone help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: No, there is no equivalent, but you can use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make a function (using python3):

```
def show(s):
    print(s + ' = ' + str(eval(s)))


for i in range(10):
    show(f"{i} ** 2")
```

This will output:

```
0 ** 2 = 0                                                                                                                                                     
1 ** 2 = 1                                                                                                                                                     
2 ** 2 = 4                                                                                                                                                     
3 ** 2 = 9                                                                                                                                                     
4 ** 2 = 16                                                                                                                                                    
5 ** 2 = 25                                                                                                                                                    
6 ** 2 = 36                                                                                                                                                    
7 ** 2 = 49                                                                                                                                                    
8 ** 2 = 64                                                                                                                                                    
9 ** 2 = 81
```

Still not as simple as `julia` but slightly easier to write than full on concatenation. Note that using `eval()` may be considered bad practice (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087255/use-of-eval-in-python)).

As for using decorators, they can only be applied to functions or classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use spyder, visual studio code or any IDE which supports debug mode.