# method in python like eval() in javascript

Tags: python, python-3.x

in javascript you can do:

```
i = -1;
array.forEach(function() {
 i++
 eval("var item" + i + " = " + array[0]);
});
```

to dynamically create variables,
used this a couple of times to write data from an external JSON array into divs for each,
is something like this possible in python(3.7)?
especially the eval() method.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there is an eval function. But you shouldn't use it. You shouldn't use it in Javascript for this either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of eval in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087255/use-of-eval-in-python)

Comment: You shouldn't do this, here is why: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is! You can use the exec function in this case:

```
i = -1

for value in array:
    i += 1
    exec("item" + str(i) + " = " + str(array[0]))
```

There are negatives to this though, as stated in the comments already, but assuming you still decide to use it here it is.