# calculation parameters in format_map()

Tags: python-3.x

I read a formatting message from database, and I want to fill message parameters from a dictionary.

The problem is where I got a mixed parameter that need calculation.

```py
data = {"p1": 10, "p2": 8}
msg = "user point is {p1+p2}" # read from database
print(msg.format_map(data))
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: There are trivial solutions that involve `eval`. But this is very likely to be a no-starter when dealing with exogenous inputs such as those that a database may provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*⚠️ Do not rely on the following if you do not know what 1) “[dynamic evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087255/use-of-eval-in-python)” exactly means and 2) what are the exact security risks (e.g. [*](https://www.thesecuritybuddy.com/vulnerabilities/what-is-dynamic-code-evaluation-attack/)) you are taking by doing so. ⚠️*

```
>>> eval(f'f"{msg}"', None, data)
'user point is 18'
```

Comment: eval is not optimize. but there is not another answer! thanx :)