# Calling Google's Custom Search API via Python

Tags: python, google-search-api

I am writing in Python a module that will query Google's Custom Search API and return all listings of domain 'example.com'

I Have been reading instructions at https://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/getting_started.html and am a little stumped at the moment.

Are my assumptions listed below correct?

For example, to search for results that has 'example.com' in the URL, the query is:

*'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=my_key&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=site:example.com'*

***key=my_key:*** value of key given by google

***cx=017576662512468239146:*** name of the search engine (google)? Is this correct?

***omuauf_lfve:*** I have no idea what this is

***q=site:example.com:*** This should return all results with 'example.com'; e.g. www.a.example.com, b.example.com, example .com

Comment: I'm getting 0 results, are you having the same issue ? Please let me know your solution.

Answer (score 5):

Though this question is quite old and the author doesn't seem to be too responsive, Google still highly ranks this page and many people may come here, so I post my answer.

Searching with Google Custom Search is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490983/google-search-with-python/4491058#4491058) answer to similar question.

Parameters are as follows:

**key** - yes, it is API key for your Google account. To obtain it go to [APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), switch on Custom Search API on *Services* tab and find actual API key on *API Access* tab.

**cx** - yes again, it is search engine unique code. Note, that this code is of form "123456:abcdef", so "omuauf_lfve" is part of this code, not the other param.

**q** - actual search query. "site:example.com" is part of Google's query language. See [search tips](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=136861&rd=1) for details.

Comment: I tried the same and it returned me 0 results, is it because `site:` is not allowed, because no-where I find not to use it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032472/how-to-query-an-advanced-search-with-google-customsearch-api) is very related, have any of you guys know how to do it? @ffriend