# Python: Access a dictionary that is located inside of a text file

Tags: python, file, google-chrome, dictionary, bookmarks

I am working on a quick and dirty script to get Chromium's bookmarks and turn them into a pipe menu for Openbox. Chromium stores it's bookmarks in a file called *Bookmarks* that stores information in a dictionary form like this:

```
{
   "checksum": "99999999999999999999",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "date_added": "9999999999999999999",
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Facebook",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "http://www.facebook.com/"
         }, {
            "date_added": "999999999999",
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Twitter",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/"
```

How would I open this dictionary in this file in Python and assign it to a variable. I know you open a file with `open()`, but I don't really know where to go from there. In the end, I want to be able to access the info in the dictionary from a variable like this `bookmarks[bookmarks_bar][children][0][name]` and have it return `'Facebook'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know if this is a json file? If so, python provides a [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) library.

Json can be used as a data serialization/interchange format. It's nice because it's cross platform. Importing this like you ask seems fairly easy, an example from the docs:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

So in your case it would look something like:

```
import json
with open(file.txt) as f:
    text = f.read()
    bookmarks = json.loads(text)
print bookmarks[bookmarks_bar][children][0][name]
```

Comment: I do not even know what a JSON file is. I apologize for my incompetency. I will check if it is.

EDIT: Yes, I found, it is a JSON file. So I'll look into that JSON library. I was hoping there would be an easier way though.

Comment: Json is actually really easy. See my example. It may not work exactly, but it will be close.

Comment: THANKS IT WORKS AMAZINGLY. I love you.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is definitely the "right" way to do this, but for a quick-and-dirty script `eval()` might suffice:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    bookmarks = eval(f.read())
```

Comment: It might work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083250/running-json-through-pythons-eval for discussion.